# Not logging to Firebase after logging to Facebook, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, swift3

I'm facing an issue after moving to Swift 3 - After the user clicks on the connect to facebook login button, nothing happens.

This is my code after moving to Swift 3:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("user logged in")
        self.loginButton.isHidden = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if error != nil {
            self.loginButton.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            print("???")
            //handle errors
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            self.loginButton.isHidden = false
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            loginManager.logOut()
            //handle cancel
            print("canceled")
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                print("user logged to firebase app")

            }
        }
```

It doesn't print `user logged in` and also doesn't print `user logged to firebase app`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will help you.

```
func fbLogin() {
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    // MARK:- Sign In with facebook.
    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError.debugDescription)")
            // handle if there is an error
        } else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled")
            // handle if facebook login was canceled
        } else {
            // Sign in to Firebase with facebook credential.
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { user, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Login failed. \(error.debugDescription)")
                    // handle alert for error
                } else {
                    guard let currentUser = user else { return }
                    print("Login success \(currentUser.uid)")
                    // do something with currentUser

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```